# Can we make the locked question default messages more clear?

Tags: feature-request

In a [recently locked post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125232/what-happens-when-a-small-army-runs-through-teleportation-circle#125232) it came to my attention that the comment proceeding the Locked banner was unclear in a way.

> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info [visit meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/).

(Where "visit meta" just links to this meta site.)

This led me and [at least one other person](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45368741#45368741) assume that a meta post already existed (or would exist) addressing the problem. Instead it seems to be an invitation to open a question in meta. There may be a better way to the word this.

I considered whether it would be good to just change the link to: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

but that seemed like it would result in more work down the line as the link would then have to be edited to accomodate an actual meta that discusses the question (to avoid needless duplicates).

Is there a way to change the phrasing to be more clear as to the intent of the message (or is this not the intent and we should update the default message anyway)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind also [pointed out](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45368709#45368709) that some of the other default messages may need updating. I didn't want to open other questions on these in case the messages are site-wide and can't really be fixed for RPG.SE individually.

Comment: The same thing was [brought up on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172783/323179) a while ago, in case you want to vote there too. It seems to be a pretty common source of confusion (I too remember experiencing the same confusion, except on Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 6):

I agree that the message is confusing.

Sure, visit meta — but why? What's there? Where's the info? (For many people, this might be their very first time seeing meta at all.) We just point them to somewhere where information *might* be *somewhere* if they can dig it up or ask about it. So we might as well just tell them something like that:

> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info, ask on meta, or search there for mention of this question.

---

> Is there a way to change the phrasing to be more clear as to the intent of the message (or is this not the intent and we should update the default message anyway)?

We can't change it ourselves, but we can make a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) suggesting it should be changed. Which you've done! Hooray!