# Where is the info regarding the dispute resolution of "What happens when a small army runs through teleportation circle?"

Tags: support, specific-question

On [What happens when a small army runs through teleportation circle?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125232/what-happens-when-a-small-army-runs-through-teleportation-circle), I read:

> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info [visit meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/).

But I couldn't find the info regarding how the disputes are going to be resolved and when we're going to be able to vote again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was locked temporarily because of an edit dispute.

I've unlocked it.

That post notice is a bit confusing and misleading and we don't have control over what it says, which is being discussed elsewhere on meta: [Can we make the locked question default messages more clear?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8095/23970). It's just an automated notice that gets added when we lock something for the reasons of content disputes.